# Remove dups in SQL server in one column based on information from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to remove duplicates in SSMS within a concat of several column, adding in an extra criteria based on another column. Basically, trying to see if the same CONCAT of Date Entered, ID, Course, Type appears more than once, and if does to delete the entry that has Status = Withdrawn

| Date Entered | ID | Course | Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/01/2021 | 1234 | NS02 | FT | Withdrawn |
| 05/01/2021 | 1234 | NS02 | FT | Continuing |
| 18/09/2022 | 2345 | AC00 | PT | Continuing |
| 20/12/2021 | 2345 | AC00 | FT | Withdrawn |
| 30/06/2020 | 4567 | FS03 | FT | Withdrawn |
| 30/06/2020 | 4567 | FS03 | FT | Continuing |

Eg.: In a correct output, row 1 and 5 would be excluded, as the CONCATs of the relevant fields are the same, and status is "Withdrawn". 4 has its status as "Withdrawn" but doesn't trigger the dup criteria based on its fields CONCAT.

I've manage to make a list of all the dups in the CONCAT - just not sure how to loop in the second criteria so only Withdrawn data is removed:

```
SELECT CONCAT([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type]) as concatfields, COUNT(*) 
--into #table
FROM [RAW].[Course_Info] 
GROUP BY CONCAT([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type])
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Also was thinking of adding this into a table so that the main data could be filtered based on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might've sorted it :') If I use the script from the question I obtain a list of all dups post concat:

```
SELECT CONCAT([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type]) as concatfields, 
COUNT(*)  AS No
INTO WIP.[Concat]
FROM [RAW].[Course_Info] 
GROUP BY CONCAT([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type])
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Then going back to the main table, I can add at the end as a filter (after any other exclusions):

```
[...]
EXCEPT SELECT * FROM [RAW].[Course_Info]   
WHERE (([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type])  IN (SELECT concatfields from WIP.[Concat]
AND [Status]  like '%Withdrawn%')
```

It's not really the prettiest way but this removes exactly what was needed. Meanwhile, my previous attempt of doing the below exclusion managed to remove a lot more than necessary in my bigger sample (I believe it excluded all 'Withdrawn' entries):

```
AND (
CONCAT([Date Entered],[ID],[Course],[Type]) NOT IN (SELECT concatfields from WIP.[Concat]) 
AND [Aim Completion Status] NOT LIKE '%Withdrawn%')
```